# Password form for iPhone (Simple)

Tags: webforms

I am trying to create a webform on the internet that is mobile. I have everything working but am confused on how to create a single password login form.

Example: You click a link and it will direct you to a password only login. The password does not have to be stored in a database but it is just asking for a password, then when you enter the right one it directs you to a website with the download and if you enter it wrong it will display a popup error saying wrong password.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has essentially nothing to do with iOS.

Comment: Are you doing this into your app by using UITextFields or?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way with .htaccess and .htpasswd files. I tried it on my website, visit [ph3nx.com/test](http://ph3nx.com/test) (Login with **username**: "test" and **password**: "1234")
It's just a directory on my webspace where i put a index.htm containing "correct" and this two files:

*.htaccess*

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/www/test/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files index.htm>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

*.htpasswd*

```
test:zYghPID4qWkpI
```

It's working with iPhone and Computer and is very simple :)
Here you can create these files: [tools.dynamicdrive.com/password](http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/)
I hope this helps you ;)